# What are the Documents involved in SDLC?

Tags: project-management

From Estimation to Delivery - thoughout the software development life cycle,

1. Which all documents are involved and
2. What is the order?

I am not sure whether methodology have much impacts on documents, anyway let us consider Waterfall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is - as has been stated - it depends.  I'm sure lots of people will answer for Agile methodologies (which are a far more movable feast) so for completeness I'll go with what you'd have for a fairly standard waterfall methodology:

- **A scope document** - very high level outlining what is and more importantly what is not in scope of the project and what assumptions are being made.  The main purpose of this document is to set expectations of what will ultimately be delivered - you're not saying how things will work but you're trying to answer questions such as will there be reporting?  Will it pass data to other systems?  Will you have to write your own user management functionality or pull from AD?  Where you can't get definite answers to these things then include an assumptions section and list what you're assuming will be the case so people can correct you if you're wrong.  It should also include things like target implementation dates (not as a commitment but so people know what is anticipated and manage expectations accordingly).
- **A functional specification** - What the application should do on a business level.  This can be divided out into business requirements (the business processes it's automating and how they work) and functional requirements (what the system does and how it does it - screen navigation, how calculations are made and so on) but more commonly they're combined except for the largest systems.  It should also include "non-functional" requirements such as performance, load, security and so on.
- **A technical specification** - The most likely to be missed out.  A detailed technical design including things such as object models, schema diagrams and information on how detailed technical problems are being addressed.
- **Test plans and test scripts** - How the application is being tested with detailed test cases, data and expected results, covering all elements of the system.
- **User guide and Release Notes** - How to install, configure and use the application.

The one I'd add to this is **a support document** - a short (less than 10 pages) crash course in what the app does and how it does it.  Developers will often not read the full specifications (either because they don't have time or don't want to) so this document should be enough to allow them to understand what it does, how it works, the areas of the application which are most likely to be problematic and so on.  It would be written a few weeks after go live by the team who built and implemented the system.

Of course depending on your methodology you may have none of these documents but if you're running a standard project in an old school structured, waterfall way, this would be pretty normal.

Answer (score 4):

I'll use the typical consulting answer... 'It Depends'.

To start, methodology has an enourmous impact on the documentation artifacts (not to mention project success), and I would place waterfall-style project management on the same level as allowing my doctor to cover me with leeches to cure a broken leg.

That being said - I have seen folks use the Microsoft Solutions Framework, and here's a link where you can grab their templates:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D2016AD-6F8A-47F5-84FA-BEC389DB18C1&displaylang=en&displaylang=en

In reality, I would strongly recommend any project to use Agile methodologies and engineering practices (at least, if you want it to have a much higher chance of success than a waterfall project).

http://www.agilealliance.com/ has some good reading, as does wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development

Good luck!

Comment: Oh no! Didn't realize we've been using leeches at work at this while :0

Answer (score 2):

In a typical production scenario, where the development is not carried out at the client location, generally waterfall model of SDLC is followed and documents pertaining to various stages of WFM are prepared:

1. Requirement gathering - Business Requirement Specification that details the complete requirement. This is functional in nature. This is accompanied by test case scenarios provided by users in which the users mention the testing and test cases that they would carryout on the desired functionality. This serves as a guideline to the development team as well to build the scope of the functionality and validations.
2. Requirement Analysis - During this phase, the BA associated with the project carried out the impact analysis and feasibility analysis. The limitations if any in the requirements, constraints, assumptions are documented, shared with the business users and signed-off to avoid any further surprises.
3. Development Approach - During this phase, the development team lead or the system analyst prepares an approach doc that defines the process flow, screen design, controls that will be placed on the screen, validations, attributes, database diagram, etc. This is then signed-off with the BA. If the development team foresee any technical constraint that will impact the desired functionality, same is shared with business team again and signed-off.
4. Testing - When the users carryout testing on the release, they validate the release based on the test cases and test scenarios provided earlier. The defects found are documented and sent back to the development team. The defects are first validated by the BA to ascertain whether the defect reported in understanding flaw, functional requirement lapse or technical bug. Accordingly resolution is provided. During this phase, care is taken that all the test cases are completed successfully and all the bugs are resolved. If any test case or bug is to be parked for next run, then basis the impact that it will have on the functionality, a joint call is taken by development team and business users on the risk involved. At the end, Business Users prepare testing sign-off document where they mention the time taken by each resource for testing, observations and process improvement suggestions.
5. Production Deployment - This includes the deployment instructions for the deployment team, server and database administrators to carryout deployment.

Feel free to provide your suggestions.